# How to test React component with useEffect and useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

In my component, there are some logic like:

```
const testRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (testRef.current) {
    doSomething();
  }
}, [testRef.current]);
```

so in unit test, how could I trigger ref change so the function inside useEffect could be called?

Comment: does you element with `ref={testRef}` rendered always or conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

To run this block your `ref` have to be in use.
Supposing that you are not using that conditionally, that you are using directly in some element so it is already triggering `doSomething()` at the first render. You can use `mount` from the Enzyme since `shallow` does not work well with hooks. So you will be able to do some assertion over what `doSomething()` does in your component.

Comment: I think the problem is how to modify the ref value so that could trigger useEffect; I'm not sure if there are any similar method like setProps() and setState(), that could be called with the shallow/mount obj

Comment: the useEffect are also triggered when the component renders at the first render. If you are already using it in some element its gonna be executing your `doSomething`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ref-useeffect?file=src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried different ways to do the test. shallow will not trigger the inner function of useEffect, maybe as you said, it works not well with hook; mount will throw some error about append child, which looks related to ref itself, while the coverage is 100%, though the test case failed.